# how to get unchecked radio button attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several **checkboxes** and **radio Buttons** with same class that user is able to select **one** of the **radio Buttons** and  **multi checkboxes**.

after checking one of them i hold sum of amount by amount attribute in variable
and after unchecked checkbox i reduce amount from sum value
but How to find the radio **attributes** that is **unselect** after choosing one of radio buttons to reduce from sum variable?

```
<input type="radio" class="form-control selected-tuitions" name="selected-tuitions[]" value="70" amount="8600000" allow-count="0" interval="0" section="2" pre-payment="8600000">
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem will be that only the **selected** **input** will be sent in your `$_POST`, so if you want to access the **unselected** in **PHP** it is a bit tricky. You can use jQuery to get the values of the unselected radios, and then store it in a hidden input which will then get posted.

```
//Add this input to your form
<input type="hidden" name="unselected-tuitions" id="unselected-tuitions">

//When the radio buttons gets clicked
$(document).on('click', '.selected-tuitions' function() {
    getUnselectedTuitions()
});

function getUnselectedTuitions() {
    let unselectedValues = [];
    //Loop through each of the unselected radio items
    $( "input.selected-tuitions:not(:checked)" ).each(function(){
        unselectedValues.push($(this).val());
    });
    //Store all the unselected values in our hidden input
    $("#unselected-tuitions").val(unselectedValues.toString());
}
```

So now you will have a hidden input with all the unselected values, which will be in the `$_POST` variable.

Comment: No, I just want to check them on the client side and not in php!

Comment: thank you for your answer but i need to last unselected radiobuttons attributes to reduce amount from sum! 
I edited my question please read it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').each(function(){

    //Your Code

});
```

Comment: $('input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').each(function(){

   alert($(this).val());
});
});

Comment: i need last unchecked radiobutton attributes! no all.

Comment: $('.selected-tuitions').change(function(){
if($(this).not(':checked')){
alert($(this).val());
}